# Excel Macro to replace string in multiple excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VB Macro to replace a string found in multiple excel files in a directory.  My code is below but it is not working and I am not sure what I need to do to fix it.

Any suggestions ?

```
Sub ReplaceStringInExcelFiles()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim orig As String
Dim news As String

orig = "cow"
news = "dog"

FilePath = "C:\myDir\"
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)


Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

Workbooks.Open (FilePath & MyFile)
For q = 1 To Application.Worksheets.Count
Worksheets(q).Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace what:=Original_String, Replacement:=New_Replacement_String, lookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next q
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
MyFile = Dir
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description of what happens when you run your code.

Comment: The code does not run

Comment: What error comes up and which line is highlighted?

Comment: There is no error when I try to run it from Excel.  But none of the files open up and get updated with the string.  No execution starts

Comment: I am new to VB.  It took me several hours to create the code and I am not sure if it is correct .  This is the reason for my posting to the website

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub ReplaceStringInExcelFiles()

    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim orig As String
    Dim news As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    orig = "cow"
    news = "dog"

    FilePath = "C:\myDir\"
    MyFile = Dir(FilePath & "*.xls*")


    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & MyFile) '<< assign the workbook to wb
        'Loop over the worksheets
        'Note: no need to activate/select
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.UsedRange.Cells.Replace what:=orig, _
                            Replacement:=news, _
                            lookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False
        Next ws
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel is known for needing clear references. Always make sure that all your objects have a path to the application object as root.

Also it is a good habit to start with

```
 option explicit
```

which helps finding such potential bugs.

Tim's code looks pretty good and should work.

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers.

Comment: I know. Mea culpa, but I am also new here and haven't yet found out how to use such simple things like a CRLF in the comment field. The help was not very helpful so far (or I overread the solution). Any hint  is more than welcome...

Comment: You can't put a newline in a comment as far as I know.  If you need to put code in a comment you can put backticks around it  like `Option Explicit`